# Can we sync data from MongoDB to Elasticsearch in realtime in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch

I am dividing the load on my Database and want to retrieve data from ES and write data to MongoDB. Can I sync them real time? I have checked the [Transporter](https://github.com/compose/transporter) library but I want to do it for realtime.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve that :

1. Using your own application server. Whenever you are inserting a new
   document in the mongo, put it in the ES as well at the same time.
   That way you will maintain the consistency with minimum latency.
2. Use logstash. It has near realtime pipelining capabilities.
3. You can use elasticsearch mongodb river. Its a plugin used for data synchronization between mongo and elasticsearch.

Comment: Wont writing data to MongoDB and ES at the same time put load on server?

Comment: no it wont, because its not a time consuming task for ES to consume a document. Its a microseconds job.